# cocos2d ccmenuitem can't access variables, ends with SIGABRT

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I have this code below. The thing is, each time I click on the "SPIN" ccmenuitem, the program crashes with a "Program received signal: SIGABRT"

Here's the output in the console:

`2011-07-29 13:52:52.906 HelloWorld[1031:207] -[NSCFString shuffle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6833c90
2011-07-29 13:52:52.976 HelloWorld[1031:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString shuffle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6833c90'`

I don't know what's wrong, my

And here is my code.

```
`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface GameScene : CCLayer {
    NSMutableArray * answersArray;    //holds all valid answers 
    NSMutableArray * lettersArray;    //holds placement of letters to display
    NSMutableArray * userAnswerArray; //holds user's answer to check and submit
    NSString * THEWORD;               //the word
}

+(id) scene;
....
- (void) spinWord;
- (void) playWord;


@end`
```

And this implementation:

`

```
@implementation GameScene

+(id) scene   {   ...    }
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
         ...//everything is initialized
         [self initImages]
         ...
    }    
}
- (void) initImages
{
    ....
    CCMenuItem *menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"PLAYunselected.png" selectedImage:@"PLAYselected.png" target:nil selector:@selector(onPlayWord)];

    CCMenuItem *menuItem2 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"SPINunselected.png" selectedImage:@"SPINselected.png" target:self selector:@selector(spinWord)];

    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1, menuItem2, nil];
    [menu alignItemsHorizontally];
    menu.position = ccp(72, 198);
    [self addChild:menu z:2];

}
- (void) spinWord{
    //NSLog(@"%@",lettersArray);   <---if I uncomment this line, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message instead
    [lettersArray shuffle];   // <--- this line causes the SIGABRT signal, even if it's initialized.
    NSLog(@"%@",lettersArray);
    ...
}
```

@end
`

Please help me out. Is this a memory management problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: may be you dont have any content in the lettersArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error always means exactly what it reads like it means.  You have sent a message to an object that does not understand that message (meaning the object does not have a method to handle such a request).  This however can also mean you are sending a message to an object that does not exist.

If you try to access a bad array index (or the index of an array that does not actually exist) you get bad access.  If you try to access a method that does not exist, or a method of an object that does not exist, you get a unrecognized selector message.

I **do not** see you allocating or initializing your arrays.  I don't know what shuffle is, you have not posted code for it.  It may be a built in method for all I know.  I am fairly certain that all you need to do is allocate and initialize your arrays.

```
NSMutableArray * answersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// And so on with your other arrays.
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have target:nil instead of target:self on menuItem1. The error is happening on menuItem2, so I'm not sure that's relevant. I was getting a very similar error just the other day, and it came down to the wrong target. Everything else in your code looks OK to me at first glance.

Comment: Yes, I changed target for menu1 to self, and that still makes it error out.

Comment: In that case I would take a long look at your lettersArray. How is it created (alloc/init), and when is it released? EXC_BAD_ACCESS usually happens when you try to access data that's been released, or isn't there in the first place.